# iOS translation apps url schemes

Tags: ios, google-translate, url-scheme

I'm trying to enable translating some text in my app. I want user to be able to launch whichever translation tool they use on their device (Google Translate or iTranslate) and see the translation without having to type it. For this, I'm using the url schemes:

```
googletranslate://
itranslate://
```

Now, I need to pass the query to those apps. I know how to do this for iTranslate:

```
itranslate://translate?from=auto&to=en&text=<encoded_string>
```

This is cool, now I would like to know how to do the same for Google Translate. It needs to automatically detect the language and translate it to english.

Comment: Refer the link: https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/detecting-the-language-from-a-text-using-the-google-translate-api-v1/

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P this explains the translation api, I'm trying to open the iOS app with parameters.

Comment: i checked it now its not working the api call refered from the link. just try this app from cocoacontrol :https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fgtranslator

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P This is for use with Google and/or Bing paid services, I want to launch the Google Translate application for iOS, I don't want to use translation apis.

Comment: from app directly you will access the google translate app?

Comment: Yes, using `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)` method you can open another application, assuming you know the url scheme that the app you want to open has registered. I know the one from Google Translate is `googletranslate://` but can't find any additional details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98118/discussion-between-harikrishnan-p-and-lawicko).

Comment: Hello. Anything came out of your chat? I'm also curious.

Comment: @GordonSun Nope, the question is still open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not currently possible to prefill UI elements in the Google Translate iOS application when opening it from `googletranslate://` URLs.  The contents of the URL after `googletranslate://` appear to be completely ignored.  So the most you can get from using these links at the moment is opening the iOS application.

If this **does** get implemented at some point in the future, one can test by opening a link like `googletranslate://example%20text/?param=value&from=zh_TW`.  I would strongly recommend that you let your voice be heard on the [Google Translate product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/translate) by requesting this feature.

In the meantime, you may want to consider using [Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/getting-started) to provide translations within your application.  This can be achieved using the REST API.

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting your answer as by now I have actually switched to using translation API as I needed something that already works.

Answer (score 3):

If is there anyone still looking for the answer, you can use it like this.

```
googletranslate://?sl=en&tl=tr&text=hello%20world
```

You can change the parameters

- sl = source language
- tl = translation language
- text = the thing you want to translate

Comment: This is great! Where / how did you find it? I'm working on a iOS Shortcut that uses this, and I'm trying to figure out how to set 'detect language' rather than setting a specific `sl=...`.

Comment: Update: I found that setting `sl=auto` sets the source language to "Detect Language", and that the language values are [ISO 639 codes](https://github.com/haliaeetus/iso-639/tree/750b7e72d245964ebc9a272137d68d8572e81e02/data). [This discussion](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/268#issuecomment-767490197) has some other potentially useful parameters.